# what is the probability distribution of a random variable Z = (X1-X2-X3)

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution

$X = (X_1,X_2,X_3)^T$ belongs to $R^3$ space has a *multivariate normal distribution* with parameters:
$$E(X) = (0,0,0)^T,$$
$$Var(X) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
 2& 0& 0\\
 0& 1& -1\\
 0& -1& 3\\
\end{array}\right).$$
Consider the random variable $Z = X_1 - X_2 - X_3$. Describe its probability distribution.

Comment: Use the self study tag.

Comment: I don't understand..

Comment: Read this and add the tag or risk having question deleted https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info no offense intended, site rule don't ya know.

Comment: @Carl no real danger of deletion; merely on hold until it is edited to fit  the policy on homework-style questions.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that a multivariate normal of any dimension has linear combinations of its components normal.  So you just need to use the available information to determine the mean and variance. `Self-study` problems do not allow us to provide a detailed answer.  This should be a good enough hint.

Comment: mean = 0 and variance = 4. So what now?

Comment: Yes the mean is 0.  Remember the variance is not the sum of the component variances if there are non-zero covariance terms.  The point is that once you know them mean and variance the normal distribution is uniquely determined.  I could have included that in the answer but I thought you might know that.